# Extract to local variable in Sublime Text

Tags: sublimetext2

In eclipse and probably other IDEs there is a refactor called "Extract to local variable".  It performs the following operations:

1. Substitutes the text under the cursor with an arbitrary variable name
2. Adds a variable declaration with the selected text on the right hand side and the generated name on the left
3. Puts the variable name in place of the selected text
4. Puts multiple cursors on the left side of the variable declaration and in the replaced text

For example:

```
do_stuff(2)
```

Becomes....

```
Var = 2,
do_stuff(Var)
```

Is there a way to automate this in Sublime Text?

Comment: what language are you using? There are a few plugins that allow some refactoring, but they're language-specific.

Comment: I mainly use sublime for writing erlang.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out that creating a plugin to do this is not so hard, it took about an hour to figure out the plugin system and get it working for my simple case.

It is saved in gist from at https://gist.github.com/andytill/7856573, there are still some things to fix.  The cursor should really be set at the variable declaration so a quick ctrl+d would edit both cases of the variable name.

```
import sublime
import sublime_plugin
import re

class IntroduceVariableCommand(sublime_plugin.TextCommand):

    var_name = "NewVar"

    def run(self, edit):

        sels = self.view.sel()

        for sel in sels:  
            if not sel.empty():
                sel_text    = self.view.substr(sel)
                top_line    = self.view.lines(sel)[0]
                top_line_text = self.view.substr(top_line)
                indentation = ""

                match = re.search(r"\W*", top_line_text, re.UNICODE)

                if match:
                    indentation = match.group(0)

                var_declaration = indentation + self.var_name + " = " + sel_text + ",\n"

                self.view.replace(edit, sel, self.var_name)

                self.view.insert(edit, top_line.a, indentation)
```

Answer (score 0):

Considering the fact that ST cannot even detect some obvious syntax errors (only basic syntax highlighting) I doubt that it would be able to do anything requiring deeper parsing and understanding of code like any form of refactoring.

IDEs like Eclipse or IntelliJ are able to do it because they are parsing code is you type it and have some really advanced databases about what dependencies are inside whole project, what are relations between variables, methods and classes and so on. AFAIK Eclipse has its own inner compiler that handles it.

Meanwhile Sublime Text is intended to be relatively simple text editor with syntax highlighting, tools that improves text edition itself. Things like project setup and running builders are nice features but they don't change the fact that authors are inspired by Vi(m) editor, not by Emacs. Notice that it sees each file as a separate thing, and cannot deduce its role in the big picture (whole project).

Perhaps someone tried that, but currently neither ST2 not ST3 are able to do it, since it would require authors to focus on implementation of language parsers for each supported language, as well as some project-scope databases of inner and outer relations and dependencies. It weren't designed to do so.

In your example, to perform refactoring program would need to:

- create new variable which would be placed before the line value was explicitly used,
- make sure that name that is used is allowed - e.g. it doesn't overshades some class variables or variable that was declared earlier/later in the code,
- in strongly-typed languages it would have to assign that variable a matching type,
- then replace value with variable without messing things up.

So even such simple task require knowledge about language's syntax and relations inside code's context. It's a lot of effort for a functionality that authors didn't even intend to have.

Comment: ST would not need to understand what it was doing, just to swap out the selected text and add the declaration in the line above.  Sort of a more complicated replace, just not sure how to do it.  Macros don't seem to work for this.

Comment: Notice that it would work this simple only for certain cases for certain languages. I suppose authors decided it's better to not have a feature than having unreliable one, which would confuse users. You need to remember that it sound simple because it's one specific case - but IDE would have to act properly with any case that might occur. Data about language syntax ST has are too simplistic to make it deduce how should it perform even the simplest refactoring in its own. Every method that would not make use of some parser, will surely have very limited use case.